# algorithm to find range sum equals to the size of the array

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I have an array A in size n of natural numbers.
I need an algorithm in O(n) that finds 2 indexes: i and j
so the sum of the sub-array A[i...j] will be divided by n with no remainder.

For example:
If I have this array:

5, 16, 10, 3, 5, 11

The sum 10+3+5 = 18 divided by the size of n ( = 6 ) with no remainder.

I don't know how to do this but I do know that modulo array is needed.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have any proof that it can be done in O(n)?

Comment: @phil1970 it is a question asked in a test in my DataStructure course. so I believe it is possible, they ask how to do it, and not if it is possible...

Comment: Well, effectively it can be done… I was able to figure it out from Setonix answer.

Comment: Does your book define the **modulo array** as it might give the answer? I never heard that term before.

Comment: @Phil1970 The question doesn't mention that, a tip from my lecturer was to use modulo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store array of prefix sum with modulo `n`, lets call this array pref_sum[]

`pref_sum[i]` will contain sum of `A[j]` with modulo `n`, where  `0 <= j <= i`

Sum of subarray `[i, j]` is divisible by `n` if `pref_sum[i] - pref_sum[j - 1] modulo n = 0`.

So for `i` with `pref_sum[i] = x`, we should find j, where `pref_sum[j - 1] = x`.

It can be found in O(1) if we store it in hash table or simple array.

Comment: Given that you need to try every `i` and `j` such that `j > i`, your algorithm will be O(n²). It could be O(n) if you would want only to find a sub-array of a specific length.

Comment: If I correctly understand the question. We should find any `i, j` where their sum is divisible by `n`. So we just iterate over array (O(n))  and calculate `pref_sum`, then for `i`, we just search `j` where `pref[j] = pref[i]` (O(1)). So, total complexity it O(n).

Comment: @Setonix Just to clarify we need a range from A[i] to A[j]. will it still work? Thank you

Comment: If for `i` we have multiple `j` where `pref[j] = pref[i]` then store maximum `j`.

Comment: While I was able to figure it out how it could be done, I find that the explication could be clearer. Essentially, you would do 2 passes:
- Initialize an array on length n with -1
- Compute the modulo of the sum up to a given index and store the index at the location given by the modulo if the value is still -1. Otherwise, the sum between stored index + 1 and current index will be a number with a modulo of 0.
Finally, you can make some adjustment depending what you really want (first sequence, longest sequence, all sequences, shortest sequence)
-

Comment: @Phil1970 I'm not sure I understand your solution. I'll try to clarify. I'm getting an array, I need to find if in the array I have a range that the **sum of their keys** will be divided by n with no devision.

Comment: @ArikRegev You need one extra container (up to size n) which have O(1) lookup and insertion. Then essentially `extra_container[cumulative_modulo] = cumulative_index` after checking if that slot was empty or not. **If you still do not understand, a paper and a pencil will help**. In fact, I was able to understand the answer that way by writing down values in a row, cumulative sum in next row, modulo in third row and mark the answer range. One that is written in a table, it is trivial to see and should not be hard to implement. **By the way, the more effort you put, the better you will get.**